# Get elements as list

Tags: java, jaxb

I have this JAXB component which I would like to get as a list:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_types")
    public TransactionTypes transactionTypes;
}


public class TransactionTypes {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transaction_type; 
    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;

    public String getTransaction_type() {
        return transaction_type;
    }
    public void setTransaction_type(String transaction_type) {
        this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

XML structure:

```
<payment>
  <transaction_types>
    <transaction_type name="type1"/>
    <transaction_type name="type2"/>
    <transaction_type name="type3"/>
  </transaction_types>
</payment>
```

The question is how I can get all transaction types as a list?

Can you give me some idea how should I modify the JAXB Object?

EDIT:

I tried this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Transaction {

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "transaction_types")
        public List<TransactionTypes> transactionTypes;
    }
```

Inner object which will hold the list:

```
    public class TransactionTypes {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transaction_type; 
    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;

    public String getTransaction_type() {
        return transaction_type;
    }
    public void setTransaction_type(String transaction_type) {
        this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the property is not a List. Change it to a `List<TransactionTypes>`, then take a look at `@XmlElementWrapper`.

Comment: Can you paste example code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `transaction_type` as a list, I have somewhat modified your code. I have introduced a new class `TransactionList` which will contain the list of `transaction_type`

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction {

@XmlElement(name = "transaction_types")
public TransactionList transactionList;

public Transaction() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Transaction [TransactionList=" + transactionList + "]";
 }
}
```

TransactionList class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TransactionList {
@XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
public List<TransactionType> transactionType;

public TransactionList(List<TransactionType> transactionTypes) {
    transactionType = transactionTypes;
}

public TransactionList() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (TransactionType transactionType : transactionType) {
        sb.append(transactionType + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

TransactionType class

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TransactionType {
@XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
private String transaction_type;
@XmlAttribute
private String name;

public TransactionType(String transaction_type, String name) {
    this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
    this.name = name;
}

public TransactionType() {
}

public String getTransaction_type() {
    return transaction_type;
}

public void setTransaction_type(String transaction_type) {
    this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TransactionTypes [transaction_type=" + transaction_type + ", name=" + name + "]";
}

}
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transaction.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Transaction transaction = (Transaction) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(FILE));
    System.out.println(transaction);
}
```

You can also check the output by directly changing the variable `transactionType` to `List` in `Transaction` table and assigning `XMLElementWrapper` annotation to it

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction {

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "transaction_types")
public List<TransactionType> transactionType;

public Transaction() {
}
}
```

Comment: Is there some other more easy way?

Comment: Check the last section of `XMLElementWrapper` that I added. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I updated the post. For some reason it's not working. Probably I need add annotation?

Comment: Try marshalling first and see how the data is generated for your setup. Is it what you expect. The `TransactionList` class I added to get the data exactly similar to your file but the data generated without it was not similar to your file

Comment: You haven't read my code properly. Check for places where I have added `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to the class. This will resolve your error